# Node reference field auto complete in views

Tags: 7, views, nodes, ajax

I have content type master program and slave program.

Slave program have node reference field with master program

I created a view for filter and show the slave program list

For node reference field it is showing as dropdown

but I want to display as autocomplete textfield.

I searched view_auto_complete and node_reference_autocomplete modules

I dont know how to implement these

Can any one help me ?

Comment: **[Have fun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkyIYnYswko)**

Comment: Are you trying to make a views 'exposed filter' autocomplete?

Comment: yes.I want to display autocomplete instead of dropdown

Comment: Have you tried using "Views Autocomplete Filter"? Here is a quick tutorial on how it works http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-views-autocomplete-filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Views Autocomplete Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) done the tricks.

Add autocomplete functionality to the views filter text fields.